# Play multiple audio files in sequence as one

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I'm trying to implement an Audio Player to play multiple files as if they were a single one. However, the initial buffer time should be only the first part's duration, and the other files should be loaded in sequence.

For example:

- File1:

  - Part1 - 0:35s
  - Part2 - 0:47s
  - Part3 - 0:07s

The File1 should be played as if it had 1:29, but we'd only wait (at most) until Part1 is loaded to start playing.

I've had a look at AVAsset, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I also thought of implementing it using AVAudioPlayer and doing all the logic myself.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVQueuePlayer/queuePlayerWithItems:) for achieving this. You need to create `AVPlayerItem` using your files url and then need to initialize the `AVQueuePlayer` using it's `queuePlayerWithItems:` method.

```
AVPlayerItem *firstItem  = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:firstPartURL];
AVPlayerItem *secondItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:secondPartURL];
AVPlayerItem *thirdItem  = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:thirdPartURL];    

NSArray *itemsToPlay     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem, nil];
AVQueuePlayer *qPlayer   = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:itemsToPlay];

[qPlayer play];
```

Comment: it solved the problem, I just had to add a observer so then I could get when the player was ready


`[qPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];`